# Read values in either one of the columns with reading multiple files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I will like to find the values in either at column 1 or 2 with reference to index row 2 (Grade).
I have tried 'and' and 'or', and it does not work.

I have 2 files:

```
     0      1     2   
0               
1    Name   john  
2    Grade  6     
3
```

---

```
     0      1     2   
0               
1    Name   Jack  
2    Grade        8
3
```

This is the final outcome I want:

```
     Name    Grade     
0     John     6
1     jack     8          
2
```

This is my code:

```
for file in files:
       df = pd.read_csv(file,header=0)
       df['Grade'] = df.iat[2,2] and [2,1]
       d.append(df)
df = pd.concat(d,ignore_index=True)
```

But the result of my code is this:

```
     Name    Grade     
0     John      6
1     Jack              
2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use if columns names are strings `'0', '1', '2'`:

```
for file in files:
       df = pd.read_csv(file,header=0)
       df['1'] = df['1'].fillna(df['2'])
       df = df.set_index('0')[['1']].T
       d.append(df)
df = pd.concat(d,ignore_index=True)
```

If working with positions use `iloc` and select columns with indexing:

```
for file in files:
       df = pd.read_csv(file,header=0)
       df.iloc[:, 1] = df.iloc[:, 1].fillna(df.iloc[:, 2])
       df = df.set_index(df.columns[0])[df.columns[1]].T
       d.append(df)
df = pd.concat(d,ignore_index=True)
```

EDIT:

Solution with [`DataFrame.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) is also possible, but I think not general:

```
d = []
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file,header=0)
    n = df.iat[1,1]

    g1 = df.iat[2,1]
    g2 = df.iat[2,2]
    out = {'Name': n, 'Grade': g1 if g1 == g1 else g2}
    d.append(out)

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)

   Name Grade
0  john     6
1  Jack     8
```

EDIT1: You can use `np.nan != np.nan`, so you can use `if-else` statement:

```
for file in files:
       df = pd.read_csv(file,header=0)

       g1 = df.iat[2,1]
       g2 = df.iat[2,2]
       df['Grade'] = g1 if g1 == g1 else g2
       d.append(df)

df = pd.concat(d,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: So there is no way to use .iat?

Comment: @weakincodingabc - Possible, give me some time

Comment: Ok, take your time.

Comment: Is there any alternatives for this part? out = {'Name': n, 'Grade': g1 if g1 == g1 else g2}... I want it something like df['Grade'] = g1 if g1 == g1 else g2

Comment: @weakincodingabc - You can try `df['Grade'] = g1 if g1 == g1 else g2`, but not sure it working, the best test it. Btw, it means give g1 if not missing else give g2

Answer (score 0):

This works !!

```
df['Grade'] = g1 if g1 == g1 else g2
```